Define an array of enum values and change that values
I would like to assign the values of an enum to an array of that enum type but I keep getting a warning that says "format '%d' expects argument of type 'int *', but argument 2 has type tShipType *"
This is the enum:
typedef enum {TRANSPORT = 1, FIGHTER, MEDICAL, EXPLORER} tShipType;

Here's the variable of type tShipType:
// Variable definitions

tShipType shipTypes[MAX_SHIPS];          // Ships type

And here is the INPUT to get the value:
// Type of ship
printf("SHIP TYPE (TRANSPORT=1, FIGHTER=2, MEDICAL=3, EXPLORER=4)?\n");
scanf("%d", &shipTypes[i]);

Should I do it like this?:
int intTo_tShipType;

    // Type of ship
    printf("SHIP TYPE (TRANSPORT=1, FIGHTER=2, MEDICAL=3, EXPLORER=4)?\n");
    scanf("%d", &intTo_tShipType);
    shipTypes[i] = intTo_tShipType;


You most likely want to do this in two steps. Read the input and check to make sure the value is valid. If it is assign it to the array, if it isn't reject it. As an example, what would you do with the value 7?

Instead of making assumptions about the underlying type, read into an integer and then copy that value by casting it to enum tShipType.

Do you mean like the code at the bottom?
